# Determine user sessions in Mysql

Tags: mysql, session

how can I determine the session times of these fictitious users?
As an example, for user 1 I assume that between 08:24:08 and 15:08:20 he wasn't there, so I don't add that time interval, I add the other times.

So I look for a method to add up (in seconds or minutes) the intermediate times based on this table. Any ideas.

```
drop table sessions;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sessions (    
    id_user int(11),
    start_date datetime
);

insert into sessions values (1,'2020-02-21 08:24:07');
insert into sessions values (1,'2020-02-21 08:24:08');--> 1 seg (08:24:08 - 08:24:07)
insert into sessions values (1,'2020-02-21 15:08:20');
insert into sessions values (1,'2020-02-21 15:08:21');--> 1 seg (15:08:21 - 15:08:20)
insert into sessions values (1,'2020-02-21 15:08:22');--> 1 seg 
insert into sessions values (2,'2020-02-20 15:08:22');
insert into sessions values (2,'2020-02-20 15:15:22');--> 7 min (15:15:22 - 15:08:22)
insert into sessions values (3,'2020-02-20 15:08:22');
insert into sessions values (3,'2020-02-20 15:15:22');--> 7 min
insert into sessions values (3,'2020-02-20 15:20:22');--> 5 min
```

Comment: *for user 1 I assume that between 08:24:08 and 15:08:20 he wasn't there*: how do you know that? Please explain the logic.

Comment: @GMB Apparently they alternate arriving/leaving.

Comment: It would be better if you had that explicitly in the data rather than having to infer it. Your current design requires that you go back to the beginning of each user to figure out which are arriving and which are leaving.

Comment: @Barmar: I am unsure... We have two consecutive records for user `1` that are taken into account:  15:08:20 > 15:08:21 and 15:08:21 > 15:08:22. Maybe they want to ignore consecutive records that have more than a certain time spacing?

Comment: Of course, that's part of the assumption. What I have are temporary records in the system, as you see in the example table. And I have to infer how much "real" time the user was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shows you how you can accomplish that in mysql 5.x and higher

Please read the Text at the end for more information

> ```
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sessions` (    
>     id_user int,
>     `start_date` datetime
> );
>
> insert into `sessions` values (1,'2020-02-21 08:24:07');
> insert into `sessions` values (1,'2020-02-21 08:24:08');
> insert into `sessions` values (1,'2020-02-21 15:08:20');
> insert into `sessions` values (1,'2020-02-21 15:08:21');
> insert into `sessions` values (1,'2020-02-21 15:08:22');
> insert into `sessions` values (2,'2020-02-20 15:08:22');
> insert into `sessions` values (2,'2020-02-20 15:15:22');
> insert into `sessions` values (3,'2020-02-20 15:08:22');
> insert into `sessions` values (3,'2020-02-20 15:15:22');
> insert into `sessions` values (3,'2020-02-20 15:20:22');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
>   IF(@iduser = id_user,TIME_FORMAT(TIMEDIFF(`start_date`,@date), '%H:%i:%S'), NULL) Datediff
>   ,@iduser := id_user iduser
>   , @date := `start_date` `start_date`
>  FROM
>   (SELECT * FROM sessions ORDER by id_user ASC, start_date ASC) t
>   ,(SELECT @iduser := 0) a,(SELECT @date := 0) b;
> ```
>
> ```
> Datediff | iduser | start_date         
> :------- | -----: | :------------------
> null     |      1 | 2020-02-21 08:24:07
> 00:00:01 |      1 | 2020-02-21 08:24:08
> 06:44:12 |      1 | 2020-02-21 15:08:20
> 00:00:01 |      1 | 2020-02-21 15:08:21
> 00:00:01 |      1 | 2020-02-21 15:08:22
> null     |      2 | 2020-02-20 15:08:22
> 00:07:00 |      2 | 2020-02-20 15:15:22
> null     |      3 | 2020-02-20 15:08:22
> 00:07:00 |      3 | 2020-02-20 15:15:22
> 00:05:00 |      3 | 2020-02-20 15:20:22
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=34ef3fe7c49b8dcb1210d166862c2050)*

It uses [TIMEDIFF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff) to get the Difference between to rows.

And the uses [TIME_FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-format) to get rid of the milliseconds.

The new **Datediff** column is at the start and must **stay there** so that the Algorithm **can work**. If you want to reorder it in mysql you need a **new** outer SELECT query.

The final problem with this algorithm is, that it simple makes time1 - time2, it doesn't care if a new day start, it would still make this for every id_user. It is possible to use a much more sophisticated ORDER BY clauses.

Comment: Thanks!, that way I can exclude the null ones and on the other hand establish a criterion to exclude the temporal differences bigger than (example) 30 min.